# JSON format using JSON_OBJECT

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I want to achieve the below JSON format using JSON_OBJECT. Please help.

```
{
  "abc": {
    "input": 10,
    "max": 20,
    "check": 30
  },
  "xyz": {
    "income": 198000
  }
}
```

Try to achieve the same using the below query.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT
(
                    'agri_Expense' VALUE 
       JSON_OBJECT(
                    'input'     VALUE 10,
                    'max'       VALUE 20,
                    'check'     VALUE 30
                  )  JSON_OBJECT('xyz'
                    JSON_OBJECT('income' VALUE( 19800 ) )
        
)
 FROM DUAL
```

Please help. syntax issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
SQL> SELECT JSON_OBJECT (
  2  'agri_Expense' VALUE
  3      JSON_OBJECT ('abc' value
  4                      JSON_OBJECT( 'input' VALUE 10, 'max' VALUE 20, 'check' VALUE 30),
  5                   'xyz' VALUE
  6                      JSON_OBJECT ( 'income' VALUE 19800 ))
  7  )
  8    FROM DUAL;

JSON_OBJECT('AGRI_EXPENSE'VALUEJSON_OBJECT('ABC'VALUEJSON_OBJECT('INPUT'VALUE10,
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"agri_Expense":{"abc":{"input":10,"max":20,"check":30},"xyz":{"income":19800}}}

SQL>
```

**Update**:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2  JSON_OBJECT ('abc' value
  3                  JSON_OBJECT( 'input' VALUE 10, 'max' VALUE 20, 'check' VALUE 30),
  4               'xyz' VALUE
  5                   JSON_OBJECT ( 'income' VALUE 19800 ))
  6    FROM DUAL;

JSON_OBJECT('ABC'VALUEJSON_OBJECT('INPUT'VALUE10,'MAX'VALUE20,'CHECK'VALUE30),'X
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"abc":{"input":10,"max":20,"check":30},"xyz":{"income":19800}}

SQL>
```

Comment: don't look my query just see the JSON structure. Query is just for your reference how I'm trying as in my query i no need agri_Expense. I need exact JSON structure which I shared

Comment: OK, That is working. Can you please help me in the below structure as well.

"abcz": [
    {
      "Field_input3": 45000, : E51
      "Minimum": "Yes",
      "Check_Input": 108000, : F51
      "Tractor_Cost": "Driver Salary" : 
    }
  ]

Comment: This should be another question and yes, this is not proper JSON